# Django rest framework pk default validation

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, if I have a retrieve view (or a detail_route or any other route that is meant to operate on a single item rather than a collection) then I have to have an argument called `pk` for the primary key or ID to be passed in.

For example:

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
     ...
     return Response(data={'id': pk})
```

My question is what kind of validation (if any) is applied to pulling the PK from the URL? Also, is there an idiomatic way to validate it, rather than writing it inline in the view itself?

I have tried looking in the docs but so far haven't seen this covered.

Comment: Not sure why there would need to be any validation on a primary key. Usually, it is the database that automatically assigns a primary key to a saved model instance so the unique and index constraints are automatically applied onto the primary key from the database side. Otherwise, if there really is some kind of default validation on a primary key, then it has to be unique and can't be blank and/or null.

Comment: So in the scenario I am working on there is no model. Instead I am pulling all data from an API from another service.

Answer (score 2):

In itself, using the `pk` should be pretty safe as it simply a `str` object. Apart from that you could use the DRF's serializer fields for validation. Lets say `pk` is a UUID. Calling `.to_internal_value()` on a field instance will validate given data and return a UUID object.

Nice thing here is that this will automatically throw a DRF `ValidationError` (in case of a invalid UUID) showing the same behaviour as if `pk` were part of a failed serializer validation.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    # throws ValidationError if pk is not a valid UUID
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField().to_internal_value(data=pk)   

    return Response(data={'id': uuid})
```

Sidenote: you could also use Django's FormFields with the `.clean()` method to the same effect, but you would need to handle the thrown exception there yourself.